# Getting all annotated controllers with @Controller

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is there a way to get a list of all Controllers, which were annotated with `@Controller`? I would like to use them like:

```
@Autowired
public void addAll(List<Controller> controllers) throws Exception {
    for (Controller controller : controllers) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in why you would want to do this?  Just curious.

Comment: Note that classes annotated with @Controller don't necessarily share a common ancestry besides java.lang.Object.

Comment: @aglassman to create documentation ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[getBeansWithAnnotation()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)

If you have annotated them with controller ... :

```
@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory;
```

then

```
Map<String, Object> controllers;
controllers = listableBeanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can probably also use the fact that `<context-component:scan />` and [BeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) does most of this for you. `@NimChimpsky` gave an excellent example.
2. You could scan the classpath, using either

   - [AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotationDeclaringClass](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotationDeclaringClass)
   - or manually using something like the following sample code

```
public List<Class> scanForComponents() {
    List<Class> components = new LinkedList<Class>();
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Component.class));

    for (String componentBasePacke : componentBasePackages) {
        for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(componentBasePacke)) {
            try {
                components.add(Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName()));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    return components;
}
```