# spring mvc get all request mappings

Tags: spring-mvc

We have a quite big spring mvc web application where the controllers are annotated with @Controller and the methods with @RequestMapping.

I would like to create a test now which checks every possible url and checks if the return value is 200.

Is it somehow possible to get all the mappings from spring ?

Comment: This is one way of getting all the mappings - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899118/204788

Comment: thanks a lot. If you make an answer, I will accept your it.

Comment: Great that this answer helps you @shifty, I have now added it as an answer.

Comment: get all controller annotated classes : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9635863/106261

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I am replicating one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898056/how-to-find-all-controllers-in-spring-mvc/10899118#10899118) here:

If you are using Spring 3.1 this handlerMapping component is an instance of RequestMappingHandlerMapping, which you can query to find the handlerMappedMethods and the associated controllers, along these lines(if you are on an older version of Spring, you should be able to use a similar approach):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Controller
public class EndpointDocController {
 private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

 @Autowired
 public EndpointDocController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
  this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/endpointdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void show(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("handlerMethods", this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());
 } 
}
```

I have provided more details on this at this url http://biju-allandsundry.blogspot.com/2012/03/endpoint-documentation-controller-for.html

This is based on a presentation on Spring 3.1 by Rossen Stoyanchev of Spring Source.

Comment: Would this also list any mapping registered with the BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping?

Comment: When using multiple RequestMappingHandlerMappings (such as with OAuth), this gives the error "No unique bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0, oauth2HandlerMapping]".  To fix it, change to List<RequestMappingHandlerMapping>

Comment: This does not include endpoints created with the `@FrameworkEndpoint`, only endpoints associated with `@Controller` and `@RestController` annotations

Comment: Using/defining @Autowired private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping; In class also works instead of defining final and having to pass it as argument and initialize it in constructor, Later on if you use a custom user made object (obviously not a controller) to initialize. It can be a problem