# In Spring 3 Web - is it possible to embed metadata as documentation in the RequestMapping annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have a large application built on Spring 3.

We're using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082818/spring-mvc-get-all-request-mappings) to build a report of all the endpoints of the application.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Controller
public class EndpointDocController {
 private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

 @Autowired
 public EndpointDocController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
  this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/endpointdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void show(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("handlerMethods", this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());
 } 
}
```

It would be really helpful if this report could include documentation about the endpoint.

My question is: **In Spring 3 Web - is it possible to embed metadata as documentation in the RequestMapping annotation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) you see that there are no additional fields for that annotation to put in documentation, so straight off, no.

However, you could create your own annotation(`@DocumentedRequestMapping`) inheriting from the `@RequestMapping` which has a field `documentation`.
Then use the handlermapping to get to the method, get it's annotations, get it's field, and that might help you.
Something like

```
Map<T,HandlerMethod> map = this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = map.get('some T');
Method annotatedMethod = handlerMethod.getMethod();
Annotation documentedRequestMappingAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(annotatedMethod, DocumentedRequestMapping.class);
Map<String, Object> annotationValues = Annotationutils.getAnnotationAttributes(documentedRequestMappingAnnotation);
annotationValues.get("documentation");
```

Mind, this is totally untested