# Why is there no qualifying bean of type RequestMappingHandlerMapping?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to autowire a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to get a list of all HTTP addresses served as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083493/2980321) and I get the following exception when Tomcat starts.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Why is there no qualifying bean of type `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` or how can I make a bean available?

I read [this page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2237) but I don't think it applies since my project doesn't use Spring Boot. String `@EnableWebMvc` isn't in my project also.
Using Spring Framework 4.3.5

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

@RequestMapping(value="/endpointdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void show(Model model) {
 model.addAttribute("handlerMethods", this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());
} 

@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        path = "/myHandlerMethods")
@ResponseBody
public String myHandlerMethods() {
    log.info("myHandlerMethods");
    System.out.println("myHandlerMethods");
    return "myHandlerMethods\n" + handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
}
```

Comment: Please add your code and I will help you more

Comment: Added code. I also created class with exact same code in the answer I mentioned, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083493/2980321. Same exception happens

Comment: @brendan what is the type of your project? is it Spring MVC? Spring Core with some additions? Spring Boot?.. what are your dependencies? as it seems like, you're not having necessary beans to support the web infrastructure. Please include all the necessary information.

Comment: I will check my Maven dependencies and compare against another project Giorgi. Good idea, thanks