# How to scan for Annotations and the values assigned to them Using Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I want to scan for @Controller @Path etc other annotations in my application (Controller), since I wanted to document the REST based services. I am not able to find an appropriate solution for the same and wanted to device my own solution. I was wondering if there is a component in Spring that would help me to scan through all the controller and help me to fetch out this information. I would like to have a custom build scanner from scratch. Please point me to the API in Spring that would help me do so. I would like to build a customized documentation tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all annotated controllers with @Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635694/getting-all-annotated-controllers-with-controller)

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html + http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html ... or maybe check how `RequestMappingHandlerMapper` is working - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java

Answer (score 0):

One way to fetch all classes from your package and check through reflection like

```
SomeController.class.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)
```

and the other good way is already specified by @Ralph